# Increase text size with bigger devices swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, swift3

I am currently working on a project and want the project to look exactly the same with every screen size. I have successfully done it with everything except the text.  For example here is what it looks like on an iPhone:

[image]

And as you can see on an iPad the text is smaller. (or remains the same size)

iPad:

[image]

I would like the text size on the iPad to increase with the size of the screen.  Any help would be really appreciated thank you!

Comment: use size classes, probably that could do the job for you, however it will be kinda clumsy UX either on iPhone or iPad, if it mimics the other idioms interface only.

Comment: Yeah I was trying to avoid that. Was seeing if there was another solution. Thanks for the reply

Comment: the size classes have been designed exactly for resolving such situations. :) here is the __[official guidance](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Size-ClassSpecificLayout.html)__ from Apple; if you feel insecure about them, you can take a tour.

Comment: @holex Thank you. I was really overthinking it

Answer (score 2):

Size Classes is your best bet.

Size classes let you set up view properties such as font size according to screen size.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some guidance.

I would suggest you calculate the font size of the text in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method.

You can call the `boundingRect(with:options:attributes:context)` method on a string to get a `CGRect` that can contain the text. Then compare this rect to the rect of the label. If it is too small, increase the font size by one and try again. Keep doing this until the text's rect is larger than the label's rect.

If you're lazy and you don't want to write the algorithm yourself, try [FittableFontLabel](https://github.com/tbaranes/FittableFontLabel).

Just create a fittable font label in the storyboard, stretch it to the size you want, add some constraints and the text's size will be calculated and set for you!

Answer (score 0):

Try the first run on the iphone 7 plus (the bigger resolution :D) with this code:

```
label?.font = self.titleLabel!.font.withSize(45)
label.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
label.textLabel?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
```

So now, check the size of text and fix it. 
When finally decide the right font size, check this on the others  emulators ( like iphone 6 and iphone 5).
Now fix the scaleFactor, but i think 0.5 generally is enough